# C++ Deleting dynamic array only deletes first element

Tags: c++, dynamic

I recently started working with and learning to understand pointers and dynamic arrays. I'm following the C++ Primer book (5th edition) which is from 2005 I believe, so I am kind of lost as to what is going on, as I feel like something has been updated along the lines.

I've searched through here and other places if this is intended behavior or if I'm just doing something wrong.

```
int main()
{
    double * p3 = new double [3];
    p3[0] = 0.2;
    p3[1] = 0.5;
    p3[2] = 0.8;

    cout << "p3 = " << p3[0] << ", " << p3[1] << ", " << p3[2] << endl;

    p3 = p3 + 1;
    cout << "Incrementing p3 = " << p3[0] << ", " << p3[1] << ", " << p3[2] << endl;

    p3 = p3 - 1;
    cout << "Decrementing p3 = " << p3[0] << ", " << p3[1] << ", " << p3[2] << endl;

    delete [] p3;
    cout << "After deleting p3 = " << p3[0] << ", " << p3[1] << ", " << p3[2];

    return 0;
}
```

What is happening is that in the book, it says that; as long as the brackets in delete are empty, it should delete the entire dynamic array, whereas in my case, it only deletes the first element (p3[0]).

I'm just wondering if it really does free the memory, but because I continue to use the pointer it creates some weird behavior or if this is what is supposed to happen and the code is wrong.

EDIT:
Output from program

```
p3 = 0.2, 0.5, 0.8
Incrementing p3 = 0.5, 0.8, 1.37017e-309
Decrementing p3 = 0.2, 0.5, 0.8
After deleting p3 = 1.63786e-305, 0.5, 0.8
```

Comment: Use standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and preferably [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). Beware of undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thing that you missed is, that standard value types like `double` do not have destructors. You see, there is simply no need to touch their memory to "clear" it, it suffices to know that the memory can be reused for something else.

As such, when you call `delete[]` on your array, most of the data in memory remains intact. However, `delete[]` decided to immediately reuse the memory that was occupied by the first `double` in your array to store some of its internal data. That is why you see the `1.63786e-305` in there. That's no double that was stored, it was likely some pointer to some other internal data.

**Touching the array's memory after `delete[]` has been called on it is undefined behavior. Anything can happen if you do. So, be sure not to do it.** Even just reading the memory as you did can immediately crash your process!

You can assert that your `delete[]` really deletes all array elements by calling it on an array of elements that actually have a destructor:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() { std::cout << "constructing Foo at " << (intptr_t)this << std::endl; }
        ~Foo() { std::cout << "destructing Foo at " << (intptr_t)this << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Foo* array = new Foo[3];
    delete[] array;
    return 0;
}
```

Running this little test program on my machine, I get the following output:

> constructing Foo at 93925438098472
>   constructing Foo at 93925438098473
>   constructing Foo at 93925438098474
>   destructing Foo at 93925438098474
>   destructing Foo at 93925438098473
>   destructing Foo at 93925438098472

As you see, all three objects got constructed, then all three objects got destructed in reverse order. Everything's fine.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot on my way to understanding how this works!

Comment: Would the downvoter(s) please mind to give an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

You have Undefined Behavior even before you delete anything. After adjusting `p3 = p3 + 1;` accessing `p3[2]` will be out of bounds. Dereferencing pointer after memory block has been freed is UB as well. And no, you can not free just first item of allocated block, only entire block. Note that you also need to use free method exactly opposite the one used for allocation: `new` - `delete`, `new []` - `delete []` or (C-style) `malloc` - `free`.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Everything works fine up until the delete part, incrementing and decrementing the pointer works just fine

Comment: @Saetre Problem is not in pointer incrementing/decrementing, it is in accessing array out of bounds `p3[2]` after incrementing pointer. Even if program does not crash right away and actually prints something it is still UB and leaves your program in inconsistent state.

Comment: So basically, I shouldn't print `p3[2]` after incrementing it, but it would be fine to do so after decrementing again?

Comment: @Saetre Yes, that should be fine.

Comment: Alright, so I fixed that, but it doesn't solve that it only deletes the first element. But, is the actual memory used freed up until I print it again after freeing it? Is that what is causing it to act weird? Because that part of the program is just for me to visually confirm that this works

Comment: @Saetre It deletes entire buffer. Dereferencing pointer after memory has been freed is Undefined Behavior. "when I run it prints some gibberish" does not confirm anything.

Comment: Freed memory is not guaranteed to look differently. But some compilers like Visual C++ in Debug mode may provide such a functionality.

Comment: @jszpilewski so in short, it works as intended, I just shouldn't continue to use it?

Comment: @Saetre Yes, such memory may stay with the program for a while or be instantly returned to the operating system but accessing it results in an undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

When the statement `delete [] p3;` is executed, the memory that was allocated for your array is being released back to the operating system, which may then re-use that memory for any process it's running. On PC, often the memory will still be reserved for the same (your) process, so accessing it will not immediately cause segmentation violation (though it is undefined behaviour). However, it might be used for other purposes (e.g. storing other information in that location on the heap). That's what happened at the location referred to by p3[0] after deleting p3.

Releasing the memory does not mean that it will be cleared (all bytes reset to 0). That is why you can still see old values when you access p3[1] and p3[2].
It just means that the memory is no more protected from being written to by any but explicit write to that address by your process.

There is no way (that I know of) for you to know whether a certain address on the heap is at the moment reserved for use by you or not, that's why it's a recommended practice to set pointers to NULL immediately after calling delete on them.

`delete [] p3;
p3 = NULL;  // or for C++11:  p3 = nullptr;`

This way you are marking for yourself: when pointer is NULL, I have released the memory that might have been associated with it.

Comment: `delete[]` does not return the memory to the OS, it returns memory to the implementation of the allocator (= the global `operator new()` and friends in the standard C++ library). Whether that library code the proceeds to return any memory back to the OS kernel, is totally up to the implementation. And, as you rightly note, in most cases, nothing will be given back to the OS.